# keep new lines in xml sent to xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my  xml file

`<node>some text1 :newLineCommand  some text2</node>`

expected output is

```
some text1
some text2
```

I'm producing the xml in java and can use anything as  `:newLineCommand`

on xsl side I use simple

```
<xsl:value-of select="/node"/>
```

So far I tried to produce XML like:

`<node>some text1 &#13;&#10;  some text2</node>`

`<node><![CDATA[some text1 <br/>  some text2]]</node>`

`<node>some text1 \n  some text2</node>`

I keep getting original XML apart from the last case where special char '\n' simply disappears from XML but new line is not achieved

Thanks for any help

Comment: which xsl version you can use?

Comment: I'm using  version 1.0

Comment: Every XSLT processor would output your text nodes as if. The improper use of CDATA sections might signal that your output is HTML. The consumer of that HTML (e.g. browsers) is responsible for visual representation, beside that in HTML there are elements that normalize whitespace only characters.

Comment: try <node>some text1 <break/>  some text2</node>